# How do I read from a png image into a numpy array of n*n features in PYTHON

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, png, python-imaging-library

I want to load a dataset and rescale it to the dimensions of another dataset with n*n dimensions or features. The dataset consists of png files, and the files are to be read one by one and stacked into a numpy array in a X * (n^2) fashion. Thus the matrix (np.array) will be (X, n^2)

Here, X is the number of data vectors and n^2 is the flattened array of n*n features. Restricted to use numpy or scipy along with PIL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.do not expect people here to write code for you from scratch.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, I do not see any problem with this approach. Is there any problem when implementing it? If so, post your code and clearly state in how far the result differs from your expectations.

Comment: Not being rude in any way, but can't post my code yet. Will post after a week though for others who might be helped by it in the future